# The spacebar on my new microsoft keyboard 4000 is acting crazy, what's causing it?

Tags: windows-7, keyboard, hardware-failure, ubuntu-12.04

This Microsoft Ergonomic 4000 keyboard is practically new, less than a month old, and today out of nowhere when using Ubuntu the spacebar stops working.

At first I thought it might be the occasional bug, so I did the usual logout/login, then disconnect/connect the keyboard, and finally rebooting. NOTHING, it was still dead.

So I booted to Windows 7, same problem, so I long-press the spacebar hoping it will react, and it did: once I released it the text started to move..........and it never stopped, as if somehow the key was stuck or I was holding it down, but neither was the case, like a very long delay effect.

Everything else in the keyboard works fine, so I really don't know if this could be a software/firmware issue or a hardware one.

Any ideas? has anyone here have the same problems?

PS: this is the **wired version**.

Comment: Have you tried to test your keyboard on a different OS, like Windows ?

Comment: @Devid YES, it says right there I booted to Windows, I even reinstalled the drivers.

Answer (score 0):

My space bar also started acting up. It would fail to register keys when I started using it. It would then work with odd delays & sometimes it would stay stuck as if it was pressed down.

After I dismantled the keyboard, I found that there's some kind of lubricant between the contact points of the thin plastic circuits that are used to register key presses.

I cleaned it up by inserting a tissue between the two layers and wipe off the lubricant.

The spacebar now works as expected, let's see if it will hold.